# Xamarin.Android binding for Infragistics Iguana - Duplicate Definition

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, infragistics

I'm trying to make a Xamarin.Android binding for Infragistics Iguana charts. I've included both common.jar and datachart.jar (if that's relevent) as EmbeddedJars.

Not knowing anything about the source for these, if I were to make common.jar an EmbeddedReferenceJar, I get 5 build errors on various types not found.

Currently, the error I get is this:

> Error CS0102: The type 'Com.Iguanaui.ValueListView' already contains a
>   definition for
>   'id_ctor_Landroid_content_Context_Landroid_util_AttributeSet_'
>   (CS0102) (Infragistics.Iguana.Binding)

Unfortunately, none of the examples in the docs seem to jive with me in terms of how I solve this specific problem.

Here is my half-hearted crack at it (in Transforms.xml):

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.iguanaui']/class[@name='ValueListView']/method[@name='id_ctor_Landroid_content_Context_Landroid_util_AttributeSet_']" name="aConstructor">Foo</attr>
```

Am I close?

Answer (score 0):

The Iguana product was retired and Infragistics has a new set of Android controls that include a data chart which does come with Xamarin bindings.  You can download a trial from the [Infragistics web site](http://www.infragistics.com/products/android/data-chart).